# Django returning static HTML in views.py?

Tags: python, html, django, http, httpresponse

So I have a standard `Django` project with a basic view that returns a simple HTML confirmation statement. Would it be plausible for me to define all of my HTML in the view itself as a really long string and return that using `HttpResponse()` I know it's a bit `unorthodox`, but this is an example of what I'm thinking about:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def index(request):
    html = """
<html>
  <body>
    This is my bare-bones html page.
  </body>
</html>
"""
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My corresponding `JS` and `stylesheets` would be stored in the same directory as views. py in my app in this example. Just making sure: I'm not asking if this works, because I already know the answer is yes, I just want to know if there are any disadvantages/drawbacks to this method, and why don't more people do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in [template renderer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template.render) to get works filters/templatetags/etc

Answer (score 0):

Most people dont use this because it mixes Python with HTML and gets very messy and out of hand very quickly

Comment: How would you do it, then, if the objective is to return static HTML?

Comment: @VinayakG. Depends on the structure of your entire site. Is your whole site just static content? What is django being used for, an api? Maybe it is fine if one single page just returns an `HttpResponse` for a small amount of content it really depends on how your site is structured. Static content is generally best served by apache or nginx for example

Comment: Sry for the (extremely) late response but I just wanted to say thanks for answering my question and to answer you question: In the context of the Django project I was asking about, I wanted to include an "about" page

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this solution works alright, but it is not adopted by many programmers because it makes the whole code disorganized and not easy to understand.
Also, this system would not be good for large projects because the code would contain lots of html in the same file as the python. It is always nice and time saving to separate code into files based on performance.

#### A better solution

Save your html in a folder called `templates` in the current directory, in this case, the `templates` folder can contain an `index.html` file which would have

```
<html>
  <body>
    This is my bare-bones html page.
  </body>
</html>
```

in the views create an index view for this template using the code below

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

##### if you would need to pass in some data to the html you can use context in the request as shown below:

```
def index(request):
    context = {
         "name":"some name"
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

access the data in html using the structure below:

```
<html>
  <body>
    The data passed to the page is {{name}}.
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps